# Using HTML in Python in sending an email

Tags: python, html, email

I am trying to send an email using python. I am trying to format my email in HTML format. Below is the code:-

```
sender = 'dummy@dummy.com'
receivers = ['abc@abc.com']
message = message = """From: team <team@temp.com>
To: To Person <me@me.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: Daily Report 
<html>
<table>
Report
<% for i in rows: %>
    <tr>
        <td> <%= rows[0][1] %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<b>This is HTML message.</b>
<h1>This is headline.</h1>
</html>
"""
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('SMTP mailer')
smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
```

I am fetching rows from Database based on some condition and storing it in "rows" variable. I am trying to loop the HTML table creation based on the number of rows returned.

Whenever i send an email it does not identify the for loop that i have written.
It does identify the "This is HTML message" in Bold form and "This is headline" in H1 format

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a [template engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955615/python-template-engine) for creating the HTML. For Python the message string you are using is just a string, nothing else. The `<% for i in rows: %>' is this very text, Python does no processing whatsoever with it.

Your mail message is not correctly formatted according to [RFC2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt):

- You must use CRLF ('\r\n') as newline separators, LF (\n') only is illegal
- Headers and body must be separated by a CRLF (i.e. one empty line).

For sending an HTML formatted message with Python, I would suggest that you use the features from `email.mime`, c.f. [How to send an email with style in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077314/how-to-send-an-email-with-style-in-python3/24077717#24077717)

Comment: Ok. I would be using Jinja2